# Why does the CSS animation continue to play even after the class name is removed?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a simple 'edit mode' feature in an app that I am building.
When the app is in edit mode, the items need to wobble.

I have added a CSS animation to achieve the wobble effect. The animation uses transforms to manipulate the orientation and position.

```
@keyframes wobble {
    0% { transform: translateY(2px) rotate(-2deg);}
    25% { transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg); }
    50% { transform: translateY(2px) rotate(2deg); }
    75% { transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: translateY(2px) rotate(-2deg); }
}
```

Then using jQuery's `toggleClass` function to trigger the animation.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.items').toggleClass('editting');
})
```

This works fine in Chrome but in Internet Explorer the animation continues to play even after the class is removed.

Strangely, clicking the button 2 extra times will stop the animation in IE.

See jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ofo7ygoL/1/)

Has anybody else experienced this before?

Comment: Hmm interesting. I would say it's that it's not properly implemented in IE, as Item 2 functions as it should for me, while the other need the 2 extra clicks. A bug that will probably never get fixed.

Comment: Actually @Jackson to help my previous point, in IE choose `inspect element` and select the `<div class="items">` and then click the button. All functions as it should.... (for me at least)

Comment: @CalvT Yes it seems to work fine. Looks like it is just a pesky IE bug

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Internet Explorer does not register animation properly when the class name is removed.

As a fix, I have added a `not-editting` class name to counteract the `editting` animation.

By adding this feature along with this CSS I am able to get Internet Explorer to behave as expected.

```
.not-editting .item {
    animation: none;
}
```

See this [updated](https://jsfiddle.net/ofo7ygoL/4/) jsFiddle